# combine option field results to text field

Tags: php, html

I tried searching this and it is probably a really simple solution but I can't figure out how to combine an option field with a text field in html/php/js. Basically I just need the user to be able to select whether it is http or https and then type in the domain. It should then be submitted through _GET as a single variable.

```
<select>
<option value="http://">http://</option>
<option value="https://">https://</option>
</select>
<input class="span4" id="domain" name="domain" type="text">
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button></form>
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would combine them AFTER the submit...

HTML Page (You need to name your `SELECT`):

```
<select name="type">
<option value="http://">http://</option>
<option value="https://">https://</option>
</select>
<input class="span4" id="domain" name="domain" type="text">
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button></form>
```

PHP Page:

```
$type = $_GET['type'];
$name = $_GET['domain'];
$combined = $type . $name;
```

Assuming you really "meant"

> submitted through _GET as a single variable

You would end up with ie. `https://` as `$type` and `www.example.com` as `$name`  ...  then the variable `$combined` should have a value of `https://www.example.com`

Comment: I really did mean sumitted through _Get as a single variable.. You can probably tell I'm still new at PHP, etc. Is this not possible or too complicated (or just foolish)? Was thinking maybe this could be done with php and a hidden form field

Comment: Then that ^^ PHP will concatenate the two variables for you and make a single.  You can do this with any variables in `PHP` using the `.`  ... You can even add a string to a variable like `$myVar . "added to my variable";`  Look into concatenation ... It comes in pretty handy.

Comment: I assure you the code I gave you up there will do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Select needs a name.

```
<form>
<select name="protocol">
<option value="http://">http://</option>
<option value="https://">https://</option>
</select>
<input class="span4" id="domain" name="domain" type="text">
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```